# jQuery get previous element not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to try and get the closest previous element like this when a checkbox is selected...

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".input1").change(function() {
    
      var myinput = jQuery(this).closest(".myinput");
    console.log(myinput);

    });  
          
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td>
    <div class="element1">
      <input class="myinput">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="element2">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="element3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="input1">
    </div>
  </td>
</table>
```

When the checkbox is clicked it gives me the original clicked element int he console log instead of the `myinput` element.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `.closest()` searches for `parent elements` that match your selector. `myinput ` is not a direct parent of the checkbox. Go to the `closest()` common parent (table) and `find()` the input from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, get the parent table and then the closest input.
After adding the .closest('table') selector the console.log shows the matched input

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".input1").change(function() {
      var myinput = 
        jQuery(this).closest('table').find(".myinput");
        console.log(myinput);

    });  
          
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td>
    <div class="element1">
      <input class="myinput">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="element2">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="element3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="input1">
    </div>
  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Great answer @ppollono, if you don't mind would be great if included why he can't find `myinput`. Since `.closest()` only find elements up the DOM tree. So he can only find `element3`, `td` and `table`. As stated in jQuery docs.